# Не появляется клавиатура

Tags: android

Ситуация такая: при установке приложения пользователь попадает на страницу, где ему необходимо залогиниться, но при нажатии на поля для ввода текста клавиатура не появляется. В чём может быть проблема? Может я что-то в манифесте не указал?

```
 <activity
            android:name=".views.activities.LoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"/>
```

Всем спасибо,вопрос решил,путём добавления в активити следующего кода:

```
 mWebView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                            v.requestFocus();
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в xml, там где ты прописываешь EditText(или ещё что то). Покажи xml-ку.

Comment: я WebView использовал

Comment: android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

А зачем эта строчка?

Comment: Покажи xml с элементом WebView и java код где работаешь с элементом, возможно, ты где то, поставил не те параметры.

Comment: там не в xml  дело,просто нужно было поставить setOnTouchListener для mWebView, а перед этим запросить фокус

Comment: @ricky по-моему это велосипед

Comment: может быть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activity на предмет клавиатуры можете совсем не трогать, скорее всего, ошибка где-то в xml.